# Wrong polygon scale after export from QGIS into FEFLOW

Tags: qgis, polygon, export, scale

I added a polygon on top of a Google Maps satellite image in QGIS which has a width of roughly 8 kilometres. When I open the respective shapefile in FEFLOW (for groundwater modelling) I see the correct silhouette but the scale is totally wrong (see screengrab below). The overall width is less than a meter (compared to approximately 8 in QGIS).

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What is the projection of your data and what are the expected units in FEFLOW?  Many CAD and CAD-like packages expect mm or cm, so passing in something that is in m or degrees will cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am not exactly sure how to find out. However, if I go on Layer Properties -> General it days "Selected CRS (EPSG:4326, WSG 84) for coordinate reference system). Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection of the polygon that you are using is WGS84 as said which is a geographic (in degree) not in meter. You need to reproject your data to save it in meter projection like UTM but you have to select the correct zone based on the location of the study area in which the polygon is drawn.

To reproject the polygon in QGIS, go to the `polygon layer in the table of content -> right-click on the layer -> Save as -> Click on the blue box` in the image below to select the desired projection in meter and give a name to the new file -> OK

[image]

**Update**

You should select the UTM zone based on the location of the study area. To know what UTM zone you have to use you can refer [UTM Grid Zones of the World](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm). The UTM zone 54N in the example above is roughly selected zone. You have to select different one based on the location of your study area.

Comment: Hi @ahmadhanb! Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the resulting layer from saving my shape file in EPSG 32654 is empty or at least I don't see any shape in QGIS, That's also the case when I open the shape file in FEFLOW ... it's completely empty. Is there any other CRS with which I could try?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I now selected WGS 72 / UTM zone 40N (for the south of Portugal). The result is much better. Actually, it could be correct. The shape is only rotated by approximately 60° but I can live with that I guess. Thanks!

Comment: I now tried "ETRS89 / Portugal TM06". Should that be correct? At least the shape has the correct angle now.

Comment: IN fact they are all a little difference. A distance which I measure in QGIS as 7655 metres is in FEFLOW 9152 metres when I saved the shape using the WGS 72 / UTM zone 40N  CRS and 6100 metre when I saved under use of WGS 72 / UTM zone 40N  ... ;(

Comment: Try to use WGS84 UTM Zone 28N or WGS84 UTM Zone 29N as Portugal is located in these two zones. Also you can find the supported CRSs for Portugal in this link http://coordtrans.com/coordtrans/guide.asp?section=SupportedCountries. Search for Portugal and try to test other CRSs if the above did not work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It still doesn't match with the distance I measure in QGIS. However, apparently I work with the wrong CRS in QGIS, right? ... I guess this would mean that I am also measuring wrong distances in QGIS and I should rather rely on e.g. GoogleMaps to measure the correct distances ... is that correct? The measured distances in GoogleMaps and FEFLOW (based on the shape saved under use of WGS84 UTM Zone 29N) correspond quite well. I guess I can then just change the CRS properties of my entire project in QGIS ... ?
Thank you for your patience and great support!

Comment: You are welcome. If CRS of WGS84 UTM Zone 29N gives you the correct measure, then this should be the right CRS that you should work with. If the answer helped you to solve the problem, then please accept and upvote the answer. This the way to say thanks in GIS.SE. :)